# Enunciate reporting - How to Exclude few APIs and include few APIs from a same class

Tags: java, rest, documentation, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I would like to exclude few API methods in a class from Enunciate documentation.

Is there a way to achieve it using enunciate ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Enunciate 1.27 has a feature "Facet"(http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Enunciate+API+Facets) which helps in achieving the above. 
Requires following changes

1.) pom.xml
Added the plugin
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.27</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>assemble</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>


2.) In the API Method you want to exclude, add Facet annotation like below

    @GET
    @Path("/{memberId}")
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Facet(name = "external")


3.) Change enunciate xml to refer to 1.27 enunciate xsd

4.) Add Facets tag in your enunciate xml

   <facets>
    <exclude name ="external"/>
   </facets>


Result - Enunciate report excludes selected APIs methods in class "A" and includes the rest.
```